# How can I filter an array of hashes to get only the keys in another array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying get a subset of keys for each hash in an array.

The hashes are actually much larger, but I figured this is easier to understand:

```
[
  {
    id:2,
    start: "3:30",
    break: 30,
    num_attendees: 14
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    start: "3: 40",
    break: 40,
    num_attendees: 4
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start: "4: 40",
    break: 10,
    num_attendees: 40
  }
]
```

I want to get only the `id` and `start` values.

I've tried:

```
return_keys = ['id','start']
return_array = events.select{|key,val|  key.to_s.in? return_keys}
```

but this returns an empty array.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
events.map do |hash|
  hash.select do |key, value|
    [:id, :start].include? key
  end
end
```

Potentially faster (but somewhat less pretty) solution:

```
events.map do |hash|
  { id: hash[:id], start: hash[:start] }
end
```

If you need `return_keys` to be dynamic:

```
return_keys = [:id, :start]
events.map do |hash|
  {}.tap do |new_hash|
    return_keys.each do |key|
      new_hash[key] = hash[key]
    end
  end
end
```

Note that, in your code, `select` picks out elements from the *array*, since that's what you called it on, but doesn't change the hashes contained within the array.

If you're concerned about performance, I've benchmarked all of the solutions listed here ([code](https://gist.github.com/1960384)):

```
                user     system      total        real
amarshall 1  0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.140316)
amarshall 2  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.066409)
amarshall 3  0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.101469)
tadman 1     0.140000   0.010000   0.150000 (  0.145489)
tadman 2     0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.111838)
mu           0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.128688)
```

Comment: For N keys in `events` and M keys in each hash, and P keys in the inner array, this performs at **O(MNP)** speed, which could be cripplingly slow.

Comment: @tadman Though, I suppose it's really O(NP)? I don't think there's anything faster than that. Assuming P is very small though, it shouldn't really affect the time complexity.

Comment: I've also updated to include code for when `return_keys` needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Awesome andrew, #2 is significantly faster, and I don't think that code is particularly un-pretty. I don't have the need for return keys to be dynamic at the moment, and the hashes can get pretty big, so I'll go for door #2.

Comment: Nice work. #2 is the optimal solution if the keys selected are small and predictable. These probably have wildly different properties if the numbers involved grow large, e.g. N=10e6, M=100, P=50, but that is only an academic consideration if the values are known to be small.

Answer (score 38):

If you happen to be using Rails (or don't mind pulling in all or part of ActiveSupport) then you could use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

```
return_array = events.map { |h| h.slice(:id, :start) }
```

[`Hash#slice`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/308595739c32609ac5b167ecdc6cb6cb4ec6c81f/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb#L15) does some extra work under the covers but it is probably fast enough that you won't notice it for small hashes and the clarity is quite nice.

Comment: Actually, you need to `require 'active_support/core_ext'` if you're not in Rails. Core extensions need to be loaded explicitly so just `require 'active_support`' doesn't work. (I say this because the latter is what most would consider "pulling in all of ActiveSupport".)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to use a hash as your index instead of doing a linear array lookup for each key:

```
events = [{id:2, start:"3:30",break:30,num_attendees:14},{id:3, start:"3:40",break:40,num_attendees:4},{id:4, start:"4:40",break:10,num_attendees:40}]

return_keys = [ :id, :start ]

# Compute a quick hash to extract the right values: { key => true }
key_index = Hash[return_keys.collect { |key| [ key, true ] }]

return_array = events.collect do |event|
  event.select do |key, value|
    key_index[key]
  end
end

# => [{:id=>2, :start=>"3:30"}, {:id=>3, :start=>"3:40"}, {:id=>4, :start=>"4:40"}]
```

I've adjusted this to use symbols as the key names to match your definition of `events`.

This can be further improved by using the `return_keys` as a direct driver:

```
events = [{id:2, start:"3:30",break:30,num_attendees:14},{id:3, start:"3:40",break:40,num_attendees:4},{id:4, start:"4:40",break:10,num_attendees:40}]

return_keys = [ :id, :start ]

return_array = events.collect do |event|
  Hash[
    return_keys.collect do |key|
      [ key, event[key] ]
    end
  ]
end
```

The result is the same. If the subset you're extracting tends to be much smaller than the original, this might be the best approach.

Comment: In case you're curious, I benchmarked all the solutions here and posted the results in my answer `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that efficiency appears to be a concern, I would suggest the following.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def keep_keys(arr, keeper_keys)
  keepers = keeper_keys.to_set
  arr.map { |h| h.select { |k,_| keepers.include?(k) } }
end
```

This uses [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-select), which, unlike [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), returns a hash. I've converted `keeper_keys` to a set for fast lookups.

**Examples**

```
arr = [{ id:2, start: "3:30", break: 30 },
       { id: 3, break: 40, num_attendees: 4 },
       { break: 10, num_attendees: 40 }]

keep_keys arr, [:id, :start]
  #=> [{:id=>2, :start=>"3:30"}, {:id=>3}, {}] 
keep_keys arr, [:start, :break]
  #=> [{:start=>"3:30", :break=>30}, {:break=>40}, {:break=>10}] 
keep_keys arr, [:id, :start, :cat]
  #=> [{:id=>2, :start=>"3:30"}, {:id=>3}, {}] 
keep_keys arr, [:start]
  #=> [{:start=>"3:30"}, {}, {}] 
keep_keys arr, [:cat, :dog]
```