# How to accumulate an array of all Active Record objects that are interconnected via "has_many" through relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using Ruby 2.7 and Rails 6.0.

I have a database that includes `People` and `Relationships`.

In `People.rb`:

```
has_many :relationships_as_parent, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => "Relationship"
has_many :children, :through => :ownerships_as_parent

has_many :relationships_as_child, :foreign_key => "child_id", :class_name => "Relationship"
has_many :parents, :through => :ownerships_as_child
```

In `Relationship.rb`:

```
belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: "parent_id", class_name: "Person"
belongs_to :child, foreign_key: "child_id", class_name: "Person"
```

If I have a family that includes six people:

- Alex
- Alex's mother
- Alex's mother's father (Alex's grandfather)
- Alex's son
- Alex's daughter
- Alex's mother's other child (Alex's sibling)

How can I run a method in my `People` model that will return an array of all six family members, and that will keep adding family members to the family tree array, until anyone related via a parent or child relationship to anyone else is included in one array? Basically, I want an array of the *whole* extended family?

What if I wanted to do the same thing in question one, but only for family members directly above and below Alex? For instance, parents of parents (of parents, etc.) and children of children (of children, etc.), but not grandparents' other children (so only going up from Alex and down from Alex, not up and then down or down and then up). Is this possible?

How do I generate an array of all of the `Relationship` records that are connecting all of the people in the `extended_family_tree` array? Can I do something like:

```
Relationship.where(parent_id.in(extended_family_tree.ids)).where(child_id.in(extended_family_tree.ids))
```

**Edit - Adding the code I have now for `family_tree`:**

```
def family
  me = [self]
  children = self.children.where.not(id: self.id)
  parents = self.parents.where.not(id: self.id)
  family = children + parents + me
end

def relationships
  child_relationships = self.relationships_as_parent.where.not(child_id: self.id)
  parent_relationships = self.relationships_as_child.where.not(parent_id: self.id)
  relationships = child_relationships + parent_relationships
end
```

Comment: You're basically talking about a double-linked list, with additional logic that limits how far a list can go, except that you could possibly have information for multiple generations, so how are you going to store that, and manage the grouping? Your question boils down to DB design. Where did you research, why didn't it help, did you write code, what was wrong with it, what is the smallest code and input data that demonstrates the problem, and what is the expected output? All those things need to be in there.

Comment: "I have a family that includes four people"? But there are six people.

Comment: I did not know that this was called a doubly-linked list, so I was struggling to accurately articulate my search terms and wasn't really coming up with much of anything that was relevant to what I am asking. Having this as a starting point, I will do more research. So far I have been able to put together an array of immediate family members but I'm not sure where to go from there. I've added the code for that above. I don't understand your question about "smallest code and input data", can you please clarify?

Comment: @theTinMan fixed typo and addressed your other questions. Thanks!

Comment: @theTinMan after a brief look into Doubly-Linked Lists, I'm not sure that Linked Lists are what I need here. I don't care about the order that my `People` records are in, and I already have the relationships between the people set up in my DB on a separate join table. I'm more specifically looking for a way to accumulate these `People` records in an array (where order doesn't matter). My original thought was nested each loops where I take Alex, add all parents to the array, then for each parent added add each of their parents, and so on until there are no more people to add.

Comment: Rails will create a linked or double-linked schema when you define the `has_many` and `belongs_to` statements, so they should be already in place.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm sorry, I'm a little new to this topic and I'm not sure what you mean. I understand that Rails creates these, but I'm not sure how they relate to what I'm trying to accomplish with an array of objects whose order does not matter.

Comment: @theTinMan I guess a simplified (and more targeted) version of my question would be "How to loop through objects related by a `has_many` through relationship using nested `each` loops when the nesting depth is unknown." Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you've configured your `has_many_through` correctly in Rails, then you should be able to simply do:

```
@person = People.find(id)
@person.relationships.to_a
```

Or the same thing with:

```
@person.family.to_a
```

An ActiveRecord::Relation object, which is what you get from the `@person.family` call, responds to the `to_a` method to convert to a standard Array.

Now you'll have an Array of hashes most likely (I'm doing this from memory) which means you'll want to iterate through the array and grab the name for a relation.

See "[How can I filter an array of hashes to get only the keys in another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538090/how-can-i-filter-an-array-of-hashes-to-get-only-the-keys-in-another-array)" for more information about iterating through an array of hashes in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works now by calling `@person.children`, which returns @person's children. However, if I want to also include each child's children (i.e. @person's grandchildren), and their children, and so on, I am stuck. I don't know how to get to the next level of family besides looping through each child and calling `.children` on them, but without knowing how many levels a family has I don't know how to nest the loops correctly. I feel like I might need a recursive function, but that's not something I've used before.

Comment: You can write a function to select only the IDs of the child objects, and then call that function until the result is nil for a specific ID, then slice that ID out of the array.  It is a bit heavy in ActiveRecord.  It sounds like what you want to do is just use pure SQL.  You would want to write an SQL query to grab any record that is tied to the Person.